# Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to php oop , so struggling a bit .

i have a database connection class viz :

```
  class config{

   protected $HOST = "localhost";
   protected $USERNAME = "something" ;
   protected $PASSWORD = "something";
   protected $DATABASE = "something";

// Constructor - open DB connection
function __construct() {

try {
    $this->db = new mysqli($this->HOST, $this->USERNAME, $this->PASSWORD, $this-
    >DATABASE);
    $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }
catch(Exception $e)
    {   
    if($this->db->connect_errno > 0){

    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    }

    }

   // Destructor - close DB connection
     function __destruct() {
    $this->db->close();
    }


 }

 $api = new Config();
```

Now i have another class from which i need to perform some tasks ...but i get FATAL error .

second class :

```
  class Myclass extends config {

   function __construct(){}

   public function myfunction()
   {
    try{


     $stmt = $this->db->stmt_init();   /* Error here : Fatal error: Call to a member                 
                                          function stmt_init() on a non-object */
 $query = "SELECT ABC FROM table " ;

 $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query); /* Error here : Fatal error: Call to a member                 
                                          function prepare() on a non-object   */
      }
     catch(){}

   }

   }
```

Please guide me with proper remedial code snippet

Comment: The proper remedy is not more code, it's learning how to debug what you already have.

Comment: whats the fata error you get?

Comment: i have commented that in my code ..please have a look at the second class code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your child class, you need to call the parent constructor. PHP won't automatically call parent constructor's when a child class is instantiated.

```
 class Myclass extends config {

     function __construct($h, $u, $p, $d){ parent::__construct($h, $u, $p, $d); }
```

Also, you don't have a `$db` property in the parent class, so add that

```
 class config{

   protected $db;
   protected $HOST = "localhost";
   protected $USERNAME = "something" ;
   protected $PASSWORD = "something";
   protected $DATABASE = "something";
```

Edit: Dependency Injection approach:

```
class config{
   public $HOST = "localhost";
   public $USERNAME = "something" ;
   public $PASSWORD = "something";
   public $DATABASE = "something";
}

class Myclass
{
   protected $db;

   function __construct($db)
   {
      $this->db = $db;
   }

   public function myfunction()
   {
       // do whatever with $this->db
   }
}

$config = new Config();

try
{
    $db = new mysqli($config->HOST, $config->USERNAME, $config->PASSWORD, $config->DATABASE);
    $db->autocommit(FALSE);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{   
    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}

$myclass = new Myclass($db);
```

Have a look into Dependency Injection. This is a favorable approach for dealing with classes that need access to a database. Instead of having all your classes extend the database, just pass the datsbase object as a parameter when creating new classes (that need the db).

Comment: Hey thanks ! this worked ... would like to know a little bit more

If instead of extending the class i make use of require_once('Config.php') ;
then what changes do i have to make ....
because this way i cant access parent constructor ....

Comment: Without extending you could create the `$db` outside of both classes, and when you create new objects based on the classes, pass the `$db` to the constructors and let the class store it as a property, so the classes can still use `$this->db` throughout.

Comment: it would be really great if you could explain me this with some small example

Comment: Added an example of basic Dependency Injection

Comment: By the way which one is the better approach  ?

extending the class OR your dependency approach  ....

consider i have no other class in my package...

Comment: I would go with the dependency injection approach. As a rule of thumb, only extend a class if the child class can be considered the same thing as the parent. Example: the parent class is `Generic_Database` and a child class is `MySQL` or `MSSQL` then the child class IS a database and so extending is a good option. Another example: parent class is `Database`, and you have another class `User`, well a user is not a database so it would be a bad choice to extend.

Answer (score 0):

Your derived class constructor is not calling the base constructor, so `$this->db` does not have the value it's supposed to. In PHP [you must do this explicitly](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

In this particular case, you should remove the derived constructor altogether since it's not doing anything. This will let PHP use the base constructor directly.